# Volley gets 400 Bad request in lollipop device but works with postman

Tags: java, android, android-volley, android-studio-3.0

I am using volley library my volley request is working perfect in nougat, oreo, marshmallow OS but its not working in lollipop device it give error **server error** I handled the error and I found error is 400 Bad request I am sharing error screenshot and also sharing my code please help me my api is also work in postman...

[image]

MY Request Code Is:

```
    private void proceedToCheakOut(){

        String tag_string_req = "req_check_out_data";
        String uri = AppConfig.URL_CHECK_OUT
                + "?userid=" + preferences.getString(SharedPref.KEY_USER_ID, "")
                + "&hotelid=" + preferences.getString(SharedPref.KEY_HOTEL_ID,"")
                + "&band=" + preferences.getString(SharedPref.KEY_BAND_ID, "")
                + "&area=" + preferences.getString(SharedPref.KEY_SEARCH_AREA, "")
                + "&check_in=" + preferences.getString(SharedPref.KEY_CHECK_IN, "")
                + "&check_out=" + preferences.getString(SharedPref.KEY_CHECK_OUT, "")
                + "&room=" + preferences.getString(SharedPref.KEY_ROOM, "")
                + "&adult=" + preferences.getString(SharedPref.KEY_ADULT, "")
                + "&above=" + preferences.getString(SharedPref.KEY_ABOVE_8, "")
                + "&below=" + preferences.getString(SharedPref.KEY_BELOW_8, "")
                + "&spouse=" + preferences.getString(SharedPref.KEY_SPOUSE, "")
                + "&days=" + preferences.getString(SharedPref.KEY_NO_OF_DAYS, "")
                + "&roomid=" + preferences.getString(SharedPref.KEY_ROOM_ID, "")
                + "&" + SharedPref.KEY_DEFENCE_ID + "=" + preferences.getString(SharedPref.KEY_DEFENCE_ID, "")
                + "&spousePrice=" + spousePrice
                + "&adultPrice=" + adultPrice
                + "&abovePrice=" + abovePrice
                + "&belowPrice=" + belowPrice
                + "&price=" + price
                + "&tax=" + tax
                + "&grandTotal=" + grandTotal
                + "&userName=" + adult1Data
                + "&userRank=" + RankData
                + "&adultList=" + adultsArray
                + "&aboveList=" + childaboveArray
                + "&belowList=" + childbelowArray;

        Log.e("URI", uri);
        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                uri, new Response.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                    // Check for error node in json
                    if (!error) {
                        Toast.makeText(CheckoutPersonalDetailActivity.this, "Booking Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(CheckoutPersonalDetailActivity.this, BookingDoneActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("grandTotal", grandTotal);
                        intent.putExtra(SharedPref.KEY_BOOKING_ID, jObj.getString("bookingid"));
                        intent.putExtra(SharedPref.KEY_BOOKING_DATE, jObj.getString("bookingdate"));
                        intent.putExtra(SharedPref.KEY_BOOKING_STATUS, jObj.getString("bookingstatus"));
                        intent.putExtra("reminderhour", jObj.getString("reminderhour"));
                        intent.putExtra("HotelImageString", hotelImgString);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        String title = "Booking Pending";
                        String description = "Booking is Pending, Your Booking Id is: "+ jObj.getString("bookingid");
       sendNotification(title, description, jObj.getString("bookingid"));
} else {
                      Toast.makeText(CheckoutPersonalDetailActivity.this,jObj.getString("error_msg"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if (error == null || error.networkResponse == null) {
                    return;
                }
               String body;
                //get status code here
                final String statusCode = String.valueOf(error.networkResponse.statusCode);
                try {
                    body = new String(error.networkResponse.data,"UTF-8");
                    Toast.makeText(CheckoutPersonalDetailActivity.this, "Error: "+body, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // exception
                }

            }

        });
        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }
```

Comment: Bad request happen when your JSON is not valid

Comment: but its working in nogut and higher than lollipop os

Comment: why ists happen its working perfect in nogut, marshmallow nut not working in lollipop, kitkat, in my app some apis is working but some are not working... its happen only in lollipop

Comment: I highly recommend you use Retrofit or read the docs for Volley because your code is an absolute mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aaaahh! Finally I solved my problem, This code help me...

```
uri = uri.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```